# Use excel vlookup to return the sum of specific columns

Tags: excel, sum, range, multiple-columns, vlookup

I'm a fairly novice excel user, and have found this formula works beautifully in adding up the specified range of cells within a set of columns:

{=SUM(VLOOKUP(A11,PLAYERS!A:BM, {31, 32, 33, 34, 35}, FALSE))}

However, is there a way of replacing the {31, 32, 33, 34, 35} with a range of columns, in my example the sum of AM:AW. If so, I want the columns that are added together to change as certain criteria changes?

Answer (score 0):

Set aside a range in the table for the column indices you want to add up, say `K1:K11`. Fill them with e.g. `=COLUMN(AM1)`...`=COLUMN(AW1)` so that you won't have to calculate the index yourself. Then use this slightly modified formula

```
{=SUM(VLOOKUP(A11,PLAYERS!A:BM, K1:K11, FALSE))}
```

as a matrix formula.